# how to download and unzip efficiently large files from a http link?

Tags: r, curl, purrr

I have a list of files such as

```
mylist <- c('http://myweb/myzip1.gz',
            'http://myweb/myzip2.gz',
            'http://myweb/myzip3.gz)
```

I need to download them and unzip them to another path `D://mydata/`.

Right now, I have used `purrr` and `download.file`

```
#get files
myfunc <- function(mystring){
  download.file(mystring,
                destfile =  paste0('D://mydata/', basename(mystring))
}

#download data
map(mylist, myfunc)
```

but after a few hours of downloads (each file is 10GB+), `Rstudio` freezes (even though the downloads still occur in the background).

Is there are more efficient way? I would like to keep track of the downloads in R without having to freeze at some point.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the info above is enough to give 'an answer' as a single code chunk, but I think there are a few things you could do that, collectively would solve the problem:

1. Try running R in terminal mode rather than the RStudio IDE proper. (This is accessible from newer versions of Rstudio.)
2. 'Chunk' the task into smaller batches, for example you could split the list of filenames using `seq_along(mylist) %/% N`, where N is the chunk size. Consider using a for loop for iterating between batches, and `purrr` only within the batches.
3. Explicitly remove files you have loaded recently into the R environment, then make explicit calls to garbage collector `gc()` to remove them from RAM.

Comment: thanks jon! A couple comments. Maybe there is another package that provides more robust downloads than the simple `download.file`. Second, here I am just downloading files to the disk, why do you think they would fill up the RAM?

Comment: third, what would you recommend to `unzip` the files efficiently when they are already on the disk?

Comment: I suspect contents are loaded into the R environment while the objects are being processed, but not sure about this. Consider adding calls to `memory.size()` or similar while the process is being run to see if this is true and the size of RAM used is accumulating. https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/r-in-a/9781449377502/ch11s05.html

If you are going to need to unzip each file it's better to do these programmatically, but maybe not at the same stage if you're running up against a RAM buffer.